# Getting NULL-values when point sampling USGS (SRTM 1 Arc-Second Global) grid (QGIS 2.8.2)

Tags: qgis, point, sampling

I use the Point Sampling Tool in QGIS to transfer gridvalues (of DEMs) to point features. This goes well with grids from f.i. MapMart (SRTMHARRIS_DEM), but I get only NULL-values when using grids from USGS (SRTM 1 Arc-Second Global). Does anybody know why and how to get proper values from SRTM 1 Arc-Second Global?

Comment: Are you sure that DEM and point layer are in the same CRS? I.e. turn OTF **OFF** and see if they still align.

Comment: I tried different CRSes which might apply, but using others the maps do not align. So I would think the CRSes are okay.

Comment: Mmm, yes, with OTF off the maps don't align. I need some more study. How to transform a map/grid from one to the another CRS?

Comment: In QGIS, `Raster -> Projection -> Reproject` to another file name and the CRS of the point file. For vector layers, you can use `Save As ...` to the CRS of the raster.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, AndreJ, you are right, thanks. For applying the “Point sample tool” the maps and grids should align with OTF **off**. After transforming the maps/grids to the same (Project) CRS (with "save as") everything went fine.